# How to send email with the html contents in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to send the mail by sending `html` contents in message everything the working fine but the in the mail I am getting whole `html` tags in the message.

below is my code:

**controller**

```
$config = Array(
      'protocol' => 'smtp',
      'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
      'smtp_port' => 465,
      'smtp_user' => 'abc@gmail.com', 
      'smtp_pass' => 'passwrd', 
      'mailtype' => 'html',
      'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
      'bcc_batch_mode' => 'true',
    );

$this->load->library("email",$config);
$data = array(
        'xyz' => $xyz,
        'abc'=> $abc,
        );
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from("abc@gmail.com","abc");
$this->email->to("xyz@gmail.com");
$this->email->subject("abc");
$body = $this->load->view('mailbody.php',$data,TRUE);
$this->email->message($body);
if($this->email->send())
      echo "Mail send successfully!";
else
     show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line

```
$body = $this->load->view('mailbody.php',$data,TRUE);
```

TO

```
$body = $this->load->view('mailbody',$data,TRUE);
```

Change the charset to utf8

Comment: @ArchanaGupta add this line

`$this->email->set_mailtype("html");`

above the following line
`$body = $this->load->view('mailbody.php',$data,TRUE);`

Answer (score 0):

you need to set charset = `utf-8`;

```
'charset' => 'utf-8', // you need to replace this line in your code
```

Comment: i tried using your answer but still the whole html code is sending in message.

Answer (score 0):

add these two in your $config array

```
'mailtype' => 'html',
'charset'  => 'utf-8',
```

Replace this line

```
$body = $this->load->view('mailbody.php',$data,TRUE);
```

with

```
$body = $this->load->view('mailbody',$data,TRUE);
```